# How to see metrics on a website broken by page

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am hosting a website on Azure as an app service and have Application Insights enabled for it. I have also inserted the following instrumentation code in each of the 5 pages on the website (with correct instrumentation key).

Microsoft has moved around the Application Insights feature on portal. My goal is to see usage analysis for each page within my website separately. The Page Views section of this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-overview) states to click on Page View section on Usage blade. I can't find Usage blade nor the page views section in it. Does anyone know how can i see the analytics shown under the Page Views section (broken by page) ?

** I know that i added instrumentation code properly because some other blades such as performance etc are breaking down the data by page.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var appInsights = window.appInsights || function(a) {
      function b(a) {
        c[a] = function() {
          var b = arguments;
          c.queue.push(function() {
            c[a].apply(c, b)
          })
        }
      }
      var c = {
          config: a
        },
        d = document,
        e = window;
      setTimeout(function() {
        var b = d.createElement("script");
        b.src = a.url || "https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", d.getElementsByTagName(
          "script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(b)
      });
      try {
        c.cookie = d.cookie
      } catch (a) {}
      c.queue = [];
      for (var f = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace", "Dependency"]; f.length;)
        b(
          "track" + f.pop());
      if (b("setAuthenticatedUserContext"), b("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"), b(
          "startTrackEvent"),
        b("stopTrackEvent"), b("startTrackPage"), b("stopTrackPage"), b("flush"), !a.disableExceptionTracking
      ) {
        f = "onerror", b("_" + f);
        var g = e[f];
        e[f] = function(a, b, d, e, h) {
          var i = g && g(a, b, d, e, h);
          return !0 !== i && c["_" + f](a, b, d, e, h), i
        }
      }
      return c
    }({
      instrumentationKey: ""
    });
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below to see if it's working for you.

Comment: does the answer below works for you?

Answer (score 1):

In Application Insights, follow the steps below:

1.Nav to `Metrics`, then click `view classic metrics`:
[image]

2.In the new page, click `Add chart`:
[image]

3.Then in the right side -> Chart details panel, select the `page view` related options:
[image]

And
[image]